# Testing how long a user has been in a list

Tags: python, bots, twitch

I'm using a bot for twitch and it tracks the time the user has spent in the channel. `!time You have spent 10 seconds in the stream`. However when multiple users use this command `!time` it doesn't have a seperate 'count' for each user. Ex:

```
Rustie: !time
Bot: Rustie, you have 20 seconds in the stream.
~1 minute later~
John: !time
Bot: John, you have 1 minute 20 seconds in the stream.
```

My current code:

```
usersForTime = []

if "time" in message:
    if user in usersForTime:
        endTime = time.time() # I already made startTime in the !start command (which starts the time tracker in the first place)
        ellapsed = (endTime - startTime)
        sendMessage(s, user + ", you have " + "%.2f" % round(ellapsed, 2) + " seconds in the stream.")
    else:
        sendMessage(s ,"You need to start tracking your time with the !start command.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to store startTime associated with a specific user, something like

```
userStart = {}

if user in usersForTime:
  ...
  ellapsed = (endTime - userStart[user])
```

which uses a dictionary to look up the individual's startTime.

To store it originally (in `!start`):

```
userStart[user] = time.time()
```